# XamDataChart with unknown number of series - Axis Titles

Tags: c#, xaml, infragistics, xamdatachart

I am working with the Infragistics xamDataChart, and plotting an unknown number of series. I am using the solution posted here, and it is working well: [XamDataChart with unknown number of series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857830/xamdatachart-with-unknown-number-of-series)

My question is on how to edit the Axis Titles generated, in XAML. I would like for there to only be generated one set of x and y axes, as I will structure my data so that these will be sufficient.

How do I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So if I am getting it right, you want to edit the name of axis? Maybe too late, but this helped me.

You can set any property of axis in method `UpdateSeriesProperties`. So for example this is how my method looks like:

```
private void UpdateSeriesProperties(Series series, SeriesType type, object seriesSource, bool shouldRenewAxes, bool clearOnly)
    {
        if (series != null)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case SeriesType.LineSeries:
                    try
                    {
                        HorizontalAnchoredCategorySeries category = series as HorizontalAnchoredCategorySeries;
                        category.ClearValue(HorizontalAnchoredCategorySeries.ValueMemberPathProperty);
                        category.ClearValue(HorizontalAnchoredCategorySeries.ItemsSourceProperty);

                        if (!clearOnly)
                        {
                            category.SetBinding(HorizontalAnchoredCategorySeries.ValueMemberPathProperty,
                                new Binding(YMemberPath) { Source = seriesSource });

                            category.SetBinding(HorizontalAnchoredCategorySeries.ItemsSourceProperty,
                                new Binding(ItemsSourcePath) { Source = seriesSource });
                        }

                        if (shouldRenewAxes)
                        {
                            if (category.XAxis != null)
                                _owner.Axes.Remove(category.XAxis);

                            if (category.YAxis != null)
                                _owner.Axes.Remove(category.YAxis);

                            if (!clearOnly)
                            {
                                CategoryDateTimeXAxis xAxis = new CategoryDateTimeXAxis();
                                xAxis.LabelSettings = new AxisLabelSettings();
                                xAxis.SetBinding(CategoryDateTimeXAxis.ItemsSourceProperty,
                                    new Binding(ItemsSourcePath) { Source = seriesSource });
                                xAxis.SetBinding(CategoryDateTimeXAxis.DateTimeMemberPathProperty,
                                    new Binding(XMemberPath) { Source = seriesSource });
                                xAxis.Label = "{" + seriesSource.GetType().GetProperty(XMemberPath).GetValue(seriesSource, null) + "}";

                                xAxis.StrokeThickness = 8;
                                xAxis.LabelSettings.Extent = 20;
                                xAxis.LabelSettings.Location = AxisLabelsLocation.OutsideBottom;
                                xAxis.LabelSettings.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;

                                NumericYAxis yAxis = new NumericYAxis();
                                yAxis.LabelSettings = new AxisLabelSettings();
                                yAxis.StrokeThickness = 2;
                                yAxis.LabelSettings.Extent = 40;
                                yAxis.LabelSettings.Location = AxisLabelsLocation.OutsideLeft;

                                yAxis.MinimumValue = Convert.ToDouble(seriesSource
                                                                        .GetType()
                                                                        .GetProperty("MinMax")
                                                                        .GetValue(seriesSource, null)
                                                                        .ToString()
                                                                        .Split(';')[0]);
                                yAxis.MaximumValue = Convert.ToDouble(seriesSource
                                                                        .GetType()
                                                                        .GetProperty("MinMax")
                                                                        .GetValue(seriesSource, null)
                                                                        .ToString()
                                                                        .Split(';')[1]);

                                if (_owner.Axes.Count == 0)
                                {
                                    yAxis.LabelSettings.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                                    _owner.Axes.Add(xAxis);
                                    _owner.Axes.Add(yAxis);

                                    category.XAxis = xAxis;
                                    category.YAxis = yAxis;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    yAxis.LabelSettings.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                                    _owner.Axes.Add(yAxis);

                                    category.XAxis = (Infragistics.Controls.Charts.CategoryAxisBase)_owner.Axes[0];
                                    category.YAxis = yAxis;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I am setting min/max values, labels, binding etc. here.

You can also set properties of Graph's Series:
You can add `Name` property in your `SeriesViewModel` like this:

```
private string name;            
public string Name          
{           
    get { return name; }            
    set { name = value; OnPropertyChagned("Name"); }            
}
```

Then you can access this property in `SeriesBinderInfo` in method `CreateSeries`:

```
series.Title = seriesSource.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(seriesSource, null);
```

You can set any property of `series` in there to reflect that in your graph.